# Erro ao tentar executar login com facebook e google native (IONIC3)

Tags: ionic, ionic3

estou com algumas dificuldades para implementar o login do google e do facebook native em um aplicativo ionic3. Os problemas que obtenho são os seguintes, no meu console :

```
main.js:71 16
main.js:84 {errorMessage: "Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 
[message]: Erro ao realizar consulta. [extra]: null"}
2main.js:71 16
```

as minhas funções são as seguintes :

```
signInWithGoogle() {
this.authService.signInWithGoogle()
  .then(() => {
    this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom', message: 
'Voce logou com o Google, Parabéns!' })
      .present();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom', message: 
'Erro ao efetuar o login' })
      .present();
  });
}


signInWithFacebook() {
this.authService.signInWithFacebook()
  .then(() => {
    this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom', message: 
 'Voce logou com o Facebook, Parabéns!' })
      .present();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom', message: 
 'Erro ao efetuar o login' })
      .present();
  });
}
```

o meu serviço de autenticação :

```
signInWithGoogle() {
return this.googlePlus.login({
  'webClientId': '427145463587
9035jdo9sji99pnn8g5sve4j6ulskd2b.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'offline': true
})
  .then(res => {
    return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithCredential
(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
      .credential(res.idToken))
      .then((user: firebase.User) => {
        // atualizando o profile do usuario
        return user.updateProfile({ displayName: res.displayName, photoURL: 
res.imageUrl });
      });
  });
}


signInWithFacebook() {
return this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
  .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
    //https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user
    //Ao logar com o facebook o profile do usuario é automaticamente 
atualizado.
    return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithCredential
(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
      .credential(res.authResponse.accessToken));
  });
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861564/server-error-code-1675030-message-error-performing-query é o mesmo erro que o seu, aparentemente é na configuração do facebook.